# how to implement subscriptions to next.js app (apollo)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo, subscription

i have a simple app, that fetch my database via graphql node.js server, and i want to implement subscriptions to it, backend is already written, but i don`t know what to do in frontend.

so i have a query and subscription, and i`m returning a map of data with messages and displaying it in my application, what i need to update, to make it work with subscriptions?

```
export const SUBSCRIPTION_MESSAGES = gql`
  subscription {
    messageCreated {
      content
      id
      user
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_MESSAGES = gql`
  query {
    messages {
      content
      id
      user
    }
  }
`;
```

```
<Messages user={state.user} />

--------------------

import { useQuery, useSubscription } from "@apollo/client";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { GET_MESSAGES, SUBSCRIPTION_MESSAGES } from "../graphql/queries";

const Messages = ({ user }: any) => {
  const { subscribeToMore, data } = useQuery(GET_MESSAGES);
  console.log(subscribeToMore);

  useEffect(() => {
    subscribeToMore({
      document: SUBSCRIPTION_MESSAGES,
      updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }: any) => {
        if (!subscriptionData.data) return prev;
        const newMessage = subscriptionData.data.messageCreated;

        return Object.assign({}, prev, {
          messages: [newMessage, ...prev.messages],
        });
      },
    });
  }, []);

  if (!data) {
    console.log("lol");
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {data.messages.map(({ id, user: messageUser, content }: any) => (
        <div
          key={id}
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: user == messageUser ? "flex-end" : "flex-start",
            paddingBottom: "1em",
          }}
        >
          {user != messageUser && (
            <div
              style={{
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                marginRight: "0.5em",
                border: "2px solid #e5e6ea",
                borderRadius: 25,
                textAlign: "center",
                fontSize: "18pt",
                paddingTop: 5,
              }}
            >
              {messageUser.slice(0, 2).toUpperCase()}
            </div>
          )}
          <div
            style={{
              background: user == messageUser ? "#58bf56" : "#e5e6ea",
              color: user == messageUser ? "white" : "black",
              paddingBottom: "1em",
              borderRadius: "1em",
              maxWidth: "60%",
              padding: "10px",
            }}
          >
            {content}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Messages;
```

Comment: At least you should wrap the `subscribeToMore` call in `useEffect`: `useEffect( () => { subscribeToMore(...) }, [])`. If it's still not working, I'd try to debug/console.log in your callback function to see (a) if you really get updates, or if the subscription is not working and (b) wether the returned object from `Object.assign` has the same structure as the prev object.

Comment: @NilsHartmann i wrapped, also i have a problem that requests are sent multiple times, and i`m encountering warning about childrens with the same key

Comment: Can you share the updated component with useEffect?

Comment: @NilsHartmann shared